# Derivative of a Riemann-Stieltjes integral (quantile regression)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, quantiles, quantile-regression, integral

(Moved from the mathematics site as I didn't receive any response there)

In pp. $5−6$ of Roger Koenker's *Quantile Regression*, the author minimizes the function

$(\tau-1)\int_{-\infty}^\hat{x}(x-\hat{x})dF(x)+\tau\int_\hat{x}^{-\infty}(x-\hat{x})dF(x)$

with respect to $\hat{x}$, where $F$ is the distribution function of an arbitrary real-valued random variable. He does this in order to show that the values of $\hat{x}$ minimizing this function are the quantiles of $F$ of order $\tau$.

In order to do that, he takes the derivative of this function with respect to $\hat{x}$ and sets it equal to zero. The problem is that this function might not even be differentiable if the distribution $F$ is not absolutely continuous (for example, if it is a discrete distribution, we would be minimizing a sum of absolute values). Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: $F$ needn't be differentiable.  See, for example, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral).